# MySQL Data Import Failing With Error -1

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I recently backed up a MySQL database in anticipation of a hardware swap out. After installing MySQL on the new hardware I attempted to import the database via MySQL WorkBench. All the tables imported correctly from the complete dump until it hit the Results file – this file contains a number of large BLObs. The preceding Random file which contains smaller BLObs imported correctly.  After a number of failures I went to an older dump of individual files with the following result:-

```
17:35:20 Restoring /media/Week 1/MySQL/Dump20141112/Physio_Results.sql 
Running: mysql --defaults-extra-file="/tmp/tmpydQEsK/extraparams.cnf"  --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments < "/media/Week 1/MySQL/Dump20141112/Physio_Results.sql" 
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 51: MySQL server has gone away 

Operation failed with exitcode 1 
17:35:21 Import of /media/Week 1/MySQL/Dump20141112/Physio_Results.sql has finished with 1 errors 

17:36:11 Restoring /media/Week 1/MySQL/Dump20141112/Physio_Session.sql 
Running: mysql --defaults-extra-file="/tmp/tmpnAksEb/extraparams.cnf"  --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments < "/media/Week 1/MySQL/Dump20141112/Physio_Session.sql" 
17:36:12 Import of /media/Week 1/MySQL/Dump20141112/Physio_Session.sql has finished
```

So obviously the larger `BLObs` are causing an issue but how do I overcome this? The documentation I looked at only says:-

```
Error Code: 2006  MySQL server has gone away
```

which adds nothing!

After increasing maxallowedpacket and netbufferlength I got slightly further, see below. I am unsure where to go next as I seem unable to restore data that I was allowed to export!

16:19:45 Restoring Physio (Results)
Running: mysql --defaults-extra-file="/tmp/tmpyme2U4/extraparams.cnf"  --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments < "/home/mjh/Desktop/Dump20141112/Physio_Results.sql"
ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 53: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

Operation failed with exitcode 1
16:19:54 Import of /home/mjh/Desktop/Dump20141112 has finished with 1 errors

Comment: Does restoring the dump from the command line also cause an error? It might help if you can determine whether this is a mysql issue or a MySQL Workbench issue

Comment: Refresh your connection.

Comment: What is the size of .sql file?

Comment: The size of the file is 8.5Gb...

Comment: Using the command line interface gave:-

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/mjh/Desktop/Dump20141112/Results.sql' INTO TABLE Results;
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (i686)' for column 'idResults' at row 1

which suggests (to me) the same issue as MySQL Workbench